# Firestore emulator not working after cloud_firestore 0.14.* upgrade

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I just upgraded to cloud_firestore 0.14.4 from 0.13.* and refactored for the breaking changes. Everything works great except my emulator broke.

Below is my new main (after refactoring) with the simple flag for switching between the local emulator and cloud firestore. Now it reads/writes to my cloud firestore database, regardless of my `usingFirebaseEmulator` value?

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final usingFirebaseEmulator = true;

  if (usingFirebaseEmulator) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = Settings(
      host: Platform.isAndroid ? '10.0.2.2:8080' : 'localhost:8080',
      sslEnabled: false,
      persistenceEnabled: false,
    );
  } else {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = Settings();
  }

  // this line now required?
  Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

EDIT: Below is my 0.13.* main(). When I switch back to its branch, the emulator populates fine.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final usingFirebaseEmulator = true;

  if (usingFirebaseEmulator) {
    Firestore.instance.settings(
      host: Platform.isAndroid ? '10.0.2.2:8080' : 'localhost:8080',
      sslEnabled: false,
      persistenceEnabled: false,
    );
  } else {
    Firestore.instance.settings();
  }

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah. I see on the [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/example) page that the the initializeApp call must come before the settings, so below worked

void main() async {
final usingFirebaseEmulator = true;

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  if (usingFirebaseEmulator) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = Settings(
      host: Platform.isAndroid ? '10.0.2.2:8080' : 'localhost:8080',
      sslEnabled: false,
      persistenceEnabled: false,
    );
  }

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```